# Who, whoever you want

Tags: meaning

Which one of the following is correct

> Vote who you want
>   Vote whoever you want

Is there difference between them?
Does it mean the same or if i add a coma would it change?

Comment: Neither is correct; neither is grammatical nor idiomatic. We vote **for** or **in favor of** one of the available options or persons: _Vote **for/in favor of** whoever you want._ (A coma will be of no help.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant the examples may not be formal, but I don't consider them to be strictly ungrammatical, it's similar to saying "Buy whatever you like", or "See whoever you want" (*whomever* is too formal). But the more idiomatic phrase, I think, would be: [**Vote for anyone you like / want**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22vote+for+anyone+you%22&tbm=bks)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes, but you "buy something" or "see something", you don't "vote somebody".  That's why **for** has to be in there for "vote".

Comment: @stangdon I think the OP may have heard "vote _how/however_ you want".

Answer (score 2):

As a pronoun you wouldn't use "Vote he", you would say "Vote for him" hence. **who** relates to **he** as **whom** relates to **him**. and **for** is required.

> Vote for whomever you want.

http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp

As a personal preference, who and whom sound better in questions.